# Unknown Error when adding an CSSearchableItem to Core Spotlight (MacOS)

Tags: swift, macos, macos-high-sierra, corespotlight

I recently wanted to power the search in one of my projects with Core Spotlight. However, whenever I add an CSSearchableItem to the SearchIndex, I get an error in the completion handler with the description:

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. (CSIndexErrorDomain error -1.)
```

According to Apple's reference, the error code `-1` refers to `Unknown Error`, which isn't exactly helpful. I added both CoreSpotlight and CoreServices frameworks to my app and I really have no idea of what I might have done wrong.

I put together a minimal example:

```
import Foundation
import CoreSpotlight

print("Start indexing...")
let attributeSet = CSSearchableItemAttributeSet(itemContentType: kUTTypeText as String)
attributeSet.title = "test element"
attributeSet.contentDescription = "This is a description."
attributeSet.keywords =  ["test1", "test2", "test3"]
let item = CSSearchableItem(uniqueIdentifier: "123455", domainIdentifier: "TestDomain", attributeSet: attributeSet)
var ready = false
CSSearchableIndex.default().indexSearchableItems([item]) { (error) in
    if error == nil {
        print("Success")
    } else {
        print(error?.localizedDescription)
    }
    ready = true
}
//Wait for the block to finish
while (ready == false) {
    sleep(1)
}
print("Finish indexing...")
```

I managed to compile Apple's example project for Core Spotlight from WWDC17, and it does in fact work without an error. However, I can't obtain the indexed items with the systemwide Spotlight search.

Does anyone have an idea what might be off? By the way, I'm running the latest High Sierra release.

[Edit] Just saw, that there is in fact someone else with this question. However, the question isn't answered yet: [Error while using CoreSpotlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46880821/error-while-using-corespotlight)

[Edit2] After updating to 10.13.2, the behaviour changed. This piece of code put in a playground is working now; however, the very same code put in my app does still produce an error, it does contain more information though. Printing the error object results in:

```
Error Domain=CSIndexErrorDomain Code=-1003 "(null)" 
UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x60000105f6e0 
{Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 
"Couldn’t communicate with a helper application."}}
```

As it displays to me, this is clearly a bug in the framework, or what do you think about that?

Comment: Do you actually have to do the `ready = false` thingy? All of the code inside of the block is executed once done, so maybe first get rid of that and see if it works then.

Comment: Also: have you included `func application(application: UIApplication, continueUserActivity userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: ([AnyObject]?) -> Void) -> Bool` method in your AppDelegate with an `import CoreSpotlight`?

Comment: This example is a macOS command line app, therefore I needed this wait-stuff to prevent the app from being terminated before the block was finished. You're referring to an iOS delegate, is there an macOS equivalent and is it really necessary? I just want to use the indexing for my in-app search with CSSearchQuery.

Comment: 'The ready = false' thing is not included in the actual app, just here in the demo to make it runnable. The problem persists.

Comment: You can `import CoreSpotlight` in your macOS AppDelegate, and I believe it is needed. AppDelegate is the only class/part of your app that's basically always running, you can't rely on ViewControllers to always stay alive.

I'd import the framework and try if Swift can type-hint it for you, because I'm not sure what the macOS equivalent is.

Comment: I just added two more lines, now you could just paste the code into a playground and it will run. For the purpose of simplicity, I chose this approach for the minimal example. In my project this happens in a much deeper layer as last part of a parsing process, I don't the 'result = false' and it still has the same problem.

Comment: Besides, as Apple states in the Core Spotlight reference that the implementation of the UserActivity is recommend to enable additional functionality, but not necessary, I figure it should work without.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With macOS 10.13, SIP and the App Sandbox seem to have become a little more strict.
After a lot of digging to get this work, here's what I did, and should work for others reading this too:

1. In Xcode, toggle the "App Sandbox" capability for your target in  which your `CoreSpotlight` code runs. If this is in a framework, it needs to be the hosting application's target. This shouldn't be necessary for new projects (for details, see [this bug report](http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=4979822228930560)).
2. Enable development signing for the application/binary which will run the CoreSpotlight code. In my case, it was the test host.

Comment: Thank for investigating that. Right now, I can't verify whether this works, but it sounds very Apple-like.

Comment: For me just doing (2) did it.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I managed to resolve the problem somehow, I followed the hint that the code was working in a playground. So I did what I wanted to do anyway and put the code in a framework.
Without any further changes, it started to work. So apparently it had to do with the project configuration but it would be great if somebody came up with an idea what's the underlying reason for Spotlight to fail.

Comment: Just posted what I think is the solution. Like you said, it's definitely a bug.